# MongoDB validate deeply nested JSON

Tags: mongodb, validation

I have a collection where I want to store the structure of a DOM from a CMS project  I am currently building.
I can store the structure and easily create the DOM back from it, and now I want to add validation to my Schema.

My questions is: Is there a way to add validation in a manner, that it will look down the whole JSON object and repeat the validation, say for the *children* array. So for all possible occurences of a *children* "key": "value" pair the validation should be performed.
Obviously, I dont't know how deep the users of the CMS will nest the HTML elements.

Here is an example document:

```
{
    "tag": "div",
    "text": "here is a div",
    "children": [
        {
            "tag": "h1",
            "text": "Hello"
        },
        {
            "tag": "h2",
            "text": "world",
            "children": [
                {
                    "tag": "h3",
                    "text": "this becomes deep...",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "tag": "h4",
                            "text": "...and even deeper..."
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

And here is my validation code:

```
{
    $jsonSchema: {
        required: ['tag'],
        properties: {
            tag: {
                bsonType: 'string',
            },
            text: {
                bsonType: ['string','int','double'],
            },
            children: {
                bsonType: 'array',
                items: {
                    bsonType: 'object',
                    required: ['tag'],
                    properties: {
                        tag: {
                            bsonType: 'string',
                        },
                        text: {
                            bsonType: ['string','int','double'],
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In my original validation I have more tests, however for the sake of simplicity this is a minimal example.

Answer (score 0):

According to MongoDB's documentation on JSON Schema, it doesn't support [external `$ref`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/jsonSchema/#omissions). Because its implementation is [based on](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/jsonSchema/#mongodb-query-op.-jsonSchema) Draft 4 and it wasn't until draft 8 (2019, "RecursiveRef") and its successor, [`$dynamicRef` in the 2020 draft](https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/json-schema-core.html#appendix-C) that inline references were possible, I don't think there's an option to do this in MongoDB's core.

Since nesting the code you already have a couple of hundred times seems a bad way to go, perhaps its better to do this validation in your client. Perhaps check up to 1, 2 or 3 levels deep in MongoDB just to be sure and leave the recursion to your app.